# OpenCart Inside Laravel is not accessible

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, opencart

I want to run opencart inside laravel. I used artisan server and placed opencart folder in public directory. Now whenever i am trying to access the ocart/upload it throws an error. That's why i am not able to install the opencart.

Please help me out. 
[image: This is Htaccess file at root Directory]

[image: Error that i am getting]

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.php|\.htaccess|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|ocart)/(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with VirtualHosts since he's using the built-in php server via `artisan server`

Comment: @FilipKoblański I don't know how to view it. :(

Comment: How about the htaccess in your ocart directory? And please paste the code directly (indented by four spaces) and not a screenshot.

Comment: @Doom5 Yes you are right. My URL directly access the Public Folder.

Comment: One notification, If i access any php file in js folder or any built in folder, it is running but in custom folder. it is not running.

Comment: `artisan server`'s emulated url rewriting must be kicking in. you can modify `server.php` to exclude paths with `/opencart` from being handled by Laravel. Note that this just a temporary solution as it's very unlikely that you'll use `artisan server` on production.